# Cycles Sun Lamp illumination

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

I'm currently working on recreating my bathroom in 3D and it's the first real project i have undertaken using blender. I have never been very strong with lighting in any 3d package but i thought i would give it a shot.

so my bathroom faces the suns direction for most of the day, this means the natural light through the window is enough to fully illuminate the entire room. I've tried to replicate this using a Sun lamp however when I shine it through the window the best it does is illuminate a patch on the wall, it barely provides any illumination to the rest of the room.

I tried changing the max bounces setting but its already set too it's max of 1024 and increasing the sun's brightness only results in brightening the patch on the wall. Is there a setting i'm missing somewhere that would increase the overall spread of the light?

Thanks

Comment: You could use ambient occlusion.

Comment: Materials play a big part on how light bounces around the scene. Also make sure to add some environment light in the World settings